# Java Socket receives Keep Alive on communication with RCON game server

Tags: java, sockets, game-development

I am currently implementing a game server manager for the RCON server protocol. I'm opening a connection to the server via a socket:

```
this.socket = new Socket();
this.socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(this.getAddress(), this.getPort()), 3000);
```

The connection works fine, I can communicate with the server and receive the responses. No problem there. My problem is that when I am debugging the communication process and i take to long getting from the request to the read on the input stream, I am getting a message "Keep Alive". This is the code for request and response:

send:

```
Rcon rcon = new Rcon();
byte[] data = rcon.constructPackage(this.getPort(), pRequestType, pPayload);
OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(data);
out.flush();
```

receive:

```
InputStream in = this.socket.getInputStream();
byte[] header = new byte[3*4];
in.read(header);

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(header);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

int length = buffer.getInt();
int id     = buffer.getInt();
int type   = buffer.getInt();
int payloadLength = length - (2*4) - 2;

byte[] payload = new byte[payloadLength];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
dis.readFully(payload);
dis.read(new byte[2]);
payloadString = new String(payload);
```

I have searched for this as Java and RCON related but I did not find a single clue where this is coming from. I'm guessing this is an RCON related effect, since I have to interpret the package which is received from the RCON server and split its contents to get to the actual payload. After this is done, the payload string contains "Keep Alive".

Comment: There's only one place it can be coming from: the peer. Presumably it is part of the RCON application protocol. Have you considered consulting the specification?

Comment: i have read through the specification several times which is pretty much just one site on [rcon protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol). I am really not sure why the server is sending this because there is nothing about it in the documentation

Comment: It's not uncommon for long running socket protocols to have their own custom "keep alive" message. Even though this is not standard for TCP, some NATs will drop the port mapping (hence lose the connection), if it sees an absence of activity on the wire. It may be expected that the client sends its own keep-alive message periodically as well, but I'm not that familiar with the RCON protocol.